# Syntax Error in Tableau for Sorting Top 10

Tags: sql, coding-style, tableau-api

SUM(IF { [Case_Type] = 'Confirmed'
and
[Date] = #01/04/2020# }
THEN CASE  END )

It is not working in Tableau since it shows Syntax Error (maybe you're missing an identifier)
Please suggest your views.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming CASE is a numeric field there are 2 issues; the {} are not needed and CASE isn't surrounded by []. Try this instead:

```
SUM(IF [Case_Type] = 'Confirmed' and [Date] = #01/04/2020# THEN [CASE] END )
```

If [CASE] isn't a number this also won't work. You could replace [CASE] with 1 instead or write more efficiently as boolean:

```
SUM(INT([Case_Type] = 'Confirmed' and [Date] = #01/04/2020#))
```